# Consume values of fields defined in Page Type in Page Template - Kentico 11

Tags: kentico

I have a set of fields defined in custom page type. After I create the page (with this respective page type) and enter the value for the fields, I want them to get displayed on the page through a custom page template. Can someone help to know how to get the values of the fields in a page template?

Comment: have you tried with `<%# Eval("fieldname") %>`?

Comment: This doesn't returns anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the template is on the custom page you should be able to do something like `{% CurrentDocument.GetValue("FieldName") %}`

Comment: This returns some abrubt value - {% CurrentDocument.GetValue("PartnerName") |(identity)GlobalAdministrator|(hash)91b99539ee113e320ad5a681d96c47adcb6094011a0385653d757ead05bef621%}

Comment: I changed the type to ASCX and it worked with the above setting